# How to automate Microsoft Excel Online version using Selenium

Tags: excel, selenium, automation, office365

Now that Office 365 Excel has come online, did any one try to automate the Grid related operations like entering values to cells and verifying them using Selenium?
I tried to inspect the Excel online page but i see that the whole row and columns are managed by Microsoft as some Canvas element rather than div or other html tags.
So i wasn't able to get the xpath of the cells in the grid because of which my plan to automate Excel stopped at the first step itself.
Please help , if anyone has done this.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use: [EXCEL JDB Driver](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/excel/jdbc/)